# Consume a WCF Duplex Service in Windows Form

Tags: wcf, forms, window, duplex

I have a `wcf` duplex service with work fine in silverlight. But the same service wants to consume in windows forms. How is it possible. My code is:

```
EndpointAddress address;
            address = new EndpointAddress("http://server08:2508/JakayaChatService");
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
                new PollingDuplexBindingElement(),
              new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
              new HttpTransportBindingElement());

            WindowsFormsApplication2.DuplexService.JakayaChatServiceClient c = new WindowsFormsApplication2.DuplexService.JakayaChatServiceClient(new InstanceContext(new myClass()),binding,address);
```

It gives me an error:

> Binding 'CustomBinding' doesn't
>   support creating any channel types.
>   This often indicates that the
>   BindingElements in a CustomBinding
>   have been stacked incorrectly or in
>   the wrong order. A Transport is
>   required at the bottom of the stack.
>   The recommended order for
>   BindingElements is: TransactionFlow,
>   ReliableSession, Security,
>   CompositeDuplex, OneWay,
>   StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding,
>   Transpor

Please provide me a sample code how to consume `WCF` duplex service in windows forms.

Comment: What does your WCF config on the Silverlight client look like?? Are you using this custom binding, too?

Comment: yes im using custom binding in silverlight.

Comment: and why can't you use the same config file (or at least parts of it) for your WInforms app? Why create everything in code?